# Are the determinants $\det[\mu(i+j-1)]_{1\le i,j\le n}$ and $\det[\mu(i+j)^2]_{1\le i,j\le n}$ always nonzero?

Tags: nt.number-theory, determinants

Let $\mu$ be the well-known Mobius function.

QUESTION: Are the Hankel-type determinants 
$$\det[\mu(i+j-1)]_{1\le i,j\le n}\ \ \text{and}\ \ 
\det[\mu(i+j)^2]_{1\le i,j\le n}$$
always nonzero?

It seems that the answer is positive 
(see http://oeis.org/A228548 and http://oeis.org/A228549 for some data) but I'm unable to prove it.

Comment: Please see this related post   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292585/determinant-of-identity-matrix-plus-hilbert-matrix

Comment: Any context for this question?

Comment: I have added links to the two related sequences in OEIS generated by me in 2013.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** an answer but I like to note an interesting variant as a claim.

We have
$$\det\left[x^{\mu(i+j)^2}\right]_{i,j=1}^n=(a_n+b_nx)\cdot(x-1)^{n-1},$$
for some integers $a_n$ and $b_n$.